# Is it possible to achieve Shiny plot interaction with multiple categorical axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm in the process of creating my first Shiny app that returns a data table when a user interacts with a ggplot object (plot) with a mouse event. Using [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction-advanced.html) from RStudio, I've been able to produce something which filters and returns a data table (diamonds) based upon the position on the x-axis (cut). Its almost there... However, I have two outstanding issues that I have been unable to solve:

1. Is it possible to return a data table based upon a mouse event that is filtered by the y-axis (color) as well as the x-axis (cut)?
2. Following from (1), can the data table then be further filtered so that it returns only information from that facet (type)?

This is where I've got up to using reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot1_click")),
  fluidRow(column(width = 10, dataTableOutput("selected_rows"))))

server <- function(input, output) {

  is.even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0

  plot <- diamonds %>%
    mutate(cut = as.factor(cut)) %>%
    mutate(colour = as.factor(color)) %>%
    mutate(type = is.even(price)) %>%
    group_by(type, color, cut) %>%
    count()

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(plot, aes(x = cut, y = color, colour = type)) +
      geom_point(aes(size = n)) +
      facet_grid(~type) +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
  })

  output$selected_rows <- renderDataTable({
    if (is.null(input$plot1_click$x)) return()

    keeprows <- round(input$plot1_click$x) == as.numeric(diamonds$cut)
    diamonds[keeprows, ]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is possible if you do a bit more logic within `output$selected_rows`. To filter by the `y` variable, simply add a reference to `input$plot1_click$y`. For the `facet` (or `panels`), you'll want to use `input$plot1_click$panelvar1`:

```
keeprows_x     <- round(input$plot1_click$x) == as.numeric(diamonds$cut)
keeprows_y     <- round(input$plot1_click$y) == as.numeric(diamonds$color)
keeprows_panel <- input$plot1_click$panelvar1 == is.even(diamonds$price)
diamonds[keeprows_x & keeprows_y & keeprows_panel, ]
```

Note: I'm mimicing the logic for `type` with `is.even(diamonds$price)`. You may want to see [this github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1433) for further discussion and solutions.

Comment: Hi @JasonAizkalns, thanks for your solution. That works a treat. Much appreciated!